# Synchronization issue using Python's multiprocessing module

Tags: python, synchronization, locking, multiprocessing

When I run the following code in from Python's multiprocessing module [page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def f(l, i):
    l.acquire()
    print 'hello world', i
    l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for num in range(10):
        Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

Sometimes I get unordered output such as:

```
hello world 0
hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 4
hello world 3
hello world 6
hello world 5
hello world 7
hello world 8
hello world 9
```

Note that 4 is printed before 3 and 6 is printed before 5. Why?

Comment: Line ten people up on one side a room, then when you shout "Go", they all have to run across and out the single door. What order do they leave in?

Comment: If you want the processes to run sequentially, don't use `multiprocessing`. You _can_ force sequential computation with the right synchronization primitives, but why? Just run them one after another in a single process. On the other hand, if you just want to get the _results_ in order, that makes sense, and there are ways to do that (trivial if you can use a pool rather than a separate process per task; non-trivial but still pretty simple if you can't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the whole point of `multiprocessing` is *parallelism*. Your processes are running at the same time as each other, so they may actually start and finish in any order.

The lock acquisition only ensures that they don't try to `print` *at the same time* - but that lock may be acquired by the various processes in any random order. It's more *likely* to be acquired by the first process you create, because that process will go through its initialization sooner and thus likely be the first one to request the lock. But there's no guaranteed of the order.

Comment: Thanks Amber, but what do they mean by "Without using the lock output from the different processes is liable to get all mixed up." in their page?

Comment: @polerto Instead of putting 1 `print` statement in your `f` function, try putting 3. You'll notice that without the lock, sometimes individual numbers will get mixed up (e.g. `1,1,2,1,2,2`) whereas with the lock, the order of the numbers might be mixed up, but identical numbers will always be together (e.g. `2,2,2,1,1,1`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the OS schedules which one runs first, and your lock only prevents more than one of them running at the same time.