# Python Synchronization Multiprocessing Lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've gone through (this SO thread)[ [Synchronization issue using Python's multiprocessing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121859/synchronization-issue-using-pythons-multiprocessing-module]) but it doesnt provide the answer.

The following code :-

```
rom multiprocessing import Process, Lock

    def f(l, i):
        l.acquire()
        print 'hello world', i
        l.release()
        # do something else

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        lock = Lock()

        for num in range(10):
            Process(target=f, args=(lock, num)).start()
```

How do I get the processes to execute in order.? I want to hold up a lock for a few seconds and then release it and thereby moving forward with the P1 and P2 into the lock, and then P2 moving forward and P3 exceuting that lock. How would I get the processes to execute in order.?

Comment: Why do you want this behavior? Forcing new processes to execute sequentially kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: There's a specific use-case.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to delay the start of each successive process. If that's the case, you can use a `multiprocessing.Event` to delay starting the next child in the main process. Just pass the event to the child, and have the child `set` the `Event` when its done doing whatever should run prior to starting the next child. The main process can `wait` on that `Event`, and once it's signalled, `clear` it and start the next child.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

def f(e, i):
    print 'hello world', i
    e.set()
    # do something else

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = Event()

    for num in range(10):
        p = Process(target=f, args=(event, num))
        p.start()
        event.wait()
        event.clear()
```

Answer (score -1):

this is not the purpose of locks. Your code architecture is bad for your use case. I think you should refactor your code to this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process    

def f(i):
    # do something here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num in range(10):
        print 'hello world', num
        Process(target=f, args=(num,)).start()
```

in this case it will print in order and then will do the remaining part asynchronously

Comment: @user1162512 please specify what you wanted